# Pandas - binning column of numeric values while preserving NaN

Tags: pandas, binning

I have a column in a dataframe which contains numeric values (such as age) and want to bin it into several categories (or ranges) like so:

`df['Age_binned'] = pd.qcut(df['Age'], 5, duplicates='drop')`

which produces following ranges:

```
(-0.001, 36.0]
(36.0, 45.0]
(45.0, 54.0]
(54.0, 62.0]
(62.0, 87.0]
```

However, I know that this column also containts some `NaN` values, which I want to treat as a separate bin. How can I accomplish this?

I tired using `.fillna()`, but if I fill `NaN` with numeric value, it gets merged with the above bins, while non-numeric values seem to be ignored by `.qcut()` method.

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected output

Comment: @Arun, what else would I provide? I want `NaN` to also be present in the list of ranges returned by `.qcut()` method, as a separate category.

Answer (score 0):

You can fill the nan with `np.nan`:

```
#dummy data:
df = pd.DataFrame({'age': np.random.choice(list(range(100)) + [None]*20, 100)})

pd.qcut(df['age'].fillna(np.nan), 5)


0     (64.0, 82.4]
1     (15.8, 39.0]
2              NaN
3     (39.0, 64.0]
4     (15.8, 39.0]
          ...     
95    (15.8, 39.0]
96    (15.8, 39.0]
97    (39.0, 64.0]
98    (64.0, 82.4]
99    (82.4, 98.0]
Name: age, Length: 100, dtype: category
Categories (5, interval[float64]): [(0.999, 15.8] < (15.8, 39.0] < (39.0, 64.0] < (64.0, 82.4] < (82.4, 98.0]]
```